# NodeJS Infinispan cache access

Tags: node.js, infinispan

**Context:**  In NodeJs I am trying to read and write in the cache to a remote server where the Infinispan deployed. Data cached in Infinispan is accessible from Java code but I am unable to access the same from NodeJS.

**Code Snippet below**

```
var infinispan = require('infinispan');             
var connected = infinispan.client({port: 11224, host: '10.232.200.XXX'}, {cacheName: 'XYZ_CACHE'});  

connected.then(function (client) {                 
var clientPut = client.put('Key1234', 'valueofCache');          
var clientGet = clientPut.then(                                                     
function() { return client.get('Key1234');        
 });   
var showGet = clientGet.then(             
function(value) { console.log('get(key)=' + value);             
 });                  
console.log(showGet));        
)}
```

Output shown on console =>

> ```
> [2016-03-28 14:32:29.447] [DEBUG] connection - Connecting to 10.232.200.XXX:11224
> [2016-03-28 14:32:29.479] [DEBUG] connection - Connected to 10.232.200.XXX:11224
>
> [2016-03-28 14:32:29.481] [DEBUG] client - Invoke put(msgId=1,key=Key1234,value=valueofCache,opts=undefined)
>
> [2016-03-28 14:32:29.485] [TRACE] router - Write buffer(msgId=1)
>
> Promise { _45: 0, _81: 0, _65: null, _54: null }
> ```

I am getting "Promise" as out put which is not the value (NULL) I am expecting. So i think even my values are not even set(put function is not working) here because if it will be set then I will be able to read it in my Java Code.

Can anyone help me in this ?

Answer (score 0):

`showGet` is indeed a Promise, that's right. Remember, you can only deal values coming out of Promises with callbacks in `then()` or similar chaining methods. Just like you did with the console output call to get the key.

So, to get the null value you're expecting, you'd have to do:

```js
showGet.then(function(thisParameterShouldBeUndefined) {
   console.log(thisParameterShouldBeUndefined);
});
```

You can find more info on using Promise API [here](https://www.promisejs.org)

Comment: In fact, to chain things properly, you should always return the last Promise created out of the last callback. So, in the last line add `return showGet`. All the examples in the [README](https://github.com/infinispan/js-client/blob/master/README.md) file do this.